# How to improve speed when creating a DOM object with JSDOM with large (~30+ MBs) html files

Tags: node.js, fs, jsdom

I'm creating a tool that reads through an html file with two embedded XML files in columns, and pulls out elements based on styling properties (they are diffs that have various diffs highlighted in different colours) with Node.js.

The files are relatively large (upwards of 30 MBs) and when I call JSDOM on the string, it takes up to a minute to parse it. There are many files, so I need it to run as quickly as possible. Is there anyway to improve performance? I'm using fs.readFile to read the data into the application.

I thought of trying to improve performance by using clusters - splitting the files into smaller pieces and using multiple cores - but I'm not sure if that is possible.

```
fs.readFile('diffsfile.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  const dom = new JSDOM(data);
}
```

Comment: from this document, do you need to get only some elements? HTML elements or XML elements?

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva - After converting it to a DOM object I'm running various checks on it using jquery, and creating a list of <a> tags that link to the diffs. I'm having to read over the file three times, once to create the DOM object, once to convert all of the relavent tags to jquery objects, and once to check whether those elements pulled out by jquery meet certain conditions. If you some way I could eliminate any of these steps, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva point being, I only need the elements that pass those tests, but I don't see how I could do them. Maybe by forgoing converting to dom at all and just treating it like text?

Comment: got it. As the slowdown is in the conversion itself (from string to DOM object), I was thinking about to eliminate first some unecessary text before to call JSDOM constructor. So the base-text to convert to DOM would be smaller.

Comment: but it might to be evaluated, depending on the method to make it, such using regular expressions. Did you tried other JSDOM-like library?  https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio is my tool for this scrapping jobs

Comment: will definitely check it out! thanks